# Apache Sqoop startup configuration error: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnClientProtocolProvider not a subtype

Tags: java, hadoop, sqoop

While starting apache sqoop getting following error, can anybody give idea to solve?

Version using are Hadoop 2.2,Sqoop 1.99.3.

Hadoop started before running sqoop.

These are running.
 SecondaryNameNode, DataNode, NodeManager,NameNode, ResourceManager, Jps, JobHistoryServer,

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.protocol.ClientProtocolProvider: Provider org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnClientProtocolProvider not a subtype
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:214)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:164)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:352)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:428)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.initialize(Cluster.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.init(JobClient.java:470)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.<init>(JobClient.java:449)
    at org.apache.sqoop.submission.mapreduce.MapreduceSubmissionEngine.initialize(MapreduceSubmissionEngine.java:113)
    at org.apache.sqoop.framework.JobManager.initialize(JobManager.java:215)
    at org.apache.sqoop.core.SqoopServer.initialize(SqoopServer.java:53)
    at org.apache.sqoop.server.ServerInitializer.contextInitialized(ServerInitializer.java:36)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
8 Apr, 2014 3:05:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
```

Answer (score 0):

Removed hadoop dependency jars from this folder.
**sqoop-1.99.3-bin-hadoop200/server/webapps/sqoop/WEB-INF/lib**

Make sure that this propery has hadoop dependencies **common.loader=usr/hadoop/lib/*.jar**